# Browsers don't recognize PHP code

Tags: php, apache, localhost, virtualhost

I created a virtual host in XAMPP for a project, but it comments all the PHP code when I run it for some reason. What can be the problem ? It loads the XAMPP localhost (localhost:80) and my Zend localhost (localhost:8000) just fine.
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jynLh.png

My httpd-vhosts.conf

```
    # Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

# Vhost for ZF2
Listen 8000
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        DocumentRoot "C:\ZendSkeletonApplication-master\public"
        <Directory "C:\ZendSkeletonApplication-master\public">
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine On
#       SetEnv ZF2_PATH "/pathtozf2lib/zendframework/library"
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
        # You have to use Junction on Win XP or mklink to create a symbolic link and add a link to assests
        # For some Apache versions
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:\codific\compudoc"
 ServerName compudoc
 ServerAlias compudoc
 <Directory "C:\codific\compudoc">
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file

```
    # Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 compudoc
```

Comment: Looks like the php module is not loaded. Check the conf again to ensure there's the php module loaded and a handler for .php files

Comment: Yes it is. It seems that it can't find the directory where PHP resides. Everything else seems to find it.

Comment: If your actual file reads as `<!--?` that should be `<?php` then `?-->` to `?>` - If it's not and is actually `<?` then make sure short tags are enabled.

Comment: At second look at your php code seems not surrounded by the php tags but only by html comments... is there a `<?php` before the code and a `?>` at the end of the php code ?

Comment: PHP code needs to be wrapped in `<?php` and `?>` for the web server to interpret it.  All you have there is an HTML comment which coincidentally happens to contain strings which *could* be used as PHP code.  The browser isn't going to do anything with that, browsers don't interpret PHP.  The browser will just ignore the HTML comment.

Comment: [It was the answer after all...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745103/browsers-dont-recognize-php-code#comment43901231_27745103), *knew it*.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screen shot you are not using the correct opening braces...

Comment: Code's not mine. My job is to do a redesign the site

Comment: Well, the stuff you were provided is non-standard php stuff and it looks to be terribly coded as well.

Comment: apache isn't going to mangle a .php script's `<?` into `<!--?`

Comment: @MarcB It could, without the full apache conf it's hard to say. Maybe the site was done with a configuration changing the open/close tags in php.ini too.

Comment: @LuckyBurger The code is pretty old and I agree that it's written terribly and without a framework it's a jungle of files

Comment: @Tensibai: it'd need a custom compile of php. there's no provision to override/change the tag definitions at the php.ini level. there's only short_open_tags to toggle between `<?php` and `<?`, and the rarely used `<%` ASP-style ones. plus, fundamentally altering php's recognized tags would break any other scripts installed ont he server and require modifying every single one to use the new tags.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks. I clearly agree with the breaking change it could give. I can't remember why I've this options in mind, maybe in an appliance probably to avoid injections in a naive way (or I'm just mixing memories ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

You just remove the `<!--?` from the first line and `--?>` from the last line .. Please use
 `<?php` and `?>`  instead of the old one .. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the guy who wrote this code was using short tags and that's why it wasn't working lol

Comment: [Seems like I was right all along... click for my original comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745103/browsers-dont-recognize-php-code#comment43901231_27745103)